# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot Read Property 'style' of undefined after defining var

Tags: javascript

I know this question has been asked a few times but by looking at the other solutions posted I still can't figure out how to get my string to work right.  Code is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function hide_column(column_order)
{
     var tbl = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
     var table_header = tbl.getElementsByTagName('th')[column_order];
     table_header.style.display=stl;
     var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr');
     for (var row=1; row<rows.length;row++)
        {     
            var cels = rows[row].getElementsByTagName('td');
            cels[column_order].style.display=stl;
        }
}
var stl='none';
hide_column(0);
hide_column(1);
hide_column(2);
hide_column(3);
hide_column(4);
hide_column(5);
</script>
```

Error I'm getting is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

I thought by identifying the property after the var I could reference it as an item?

Thank you for any guidance; I'm not good with javascript...

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you're trying to access a column at an index that is `>=` to the number of columns.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: I have a table (5 columns wide) that I'm hiding.  The longer version of the code checks for a few variables before executing the function but I need to get it to just hide every time first so I know it works.

Comment: @AlexFenech, why are you hiding columns when your goal is to hide the table? Please add your html to the question.

Comment: @Pyromonk it's all a shortcode so I'm having a hard time getting the underlying HTML.  I'm sorry...I'm still working on finding it/getting it formatted (I can get part of it but it's a massive paragraph of text which doesn't really help).  In relation to your question, I couldn't get the script to work right in the source platform to hide the entire table, but by hiding columns, the source platform would hide it correctly.

Comment: @AlexFenech, that's very peculiar, I am curious how exactly you were trying to hide it and how exactly your page is set up. I could give you a general example for how one would hide a table in javascript, but that would not help you in the long run. Also, which line exactly is returning undefined?

Comment: @Pyromonk I am so sorry.  This was a poorly posted question without the needed information.  For what it's worth, I eventually opened a div with an ID then hid the div using script.

Comment: @AlexFenech, I apologise I couldn't help you, and I am glad you have managed to solve the problem eventually. [You don't necessarily need an id to get to an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).